# How to sort list inside dict in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical

I am trying to sort list inside of dict alphabetically but not able to do it. My list is

```
{"B" : ["x", "z", "k"], "A" : ["a", "c", "b"]}
```

What I want to do is,

```
{"A" : ["k", "x", "z"], "B" : ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

my codes are

```
a = {"B" : ["x", "z", "k"], "A" : ["a", "c", "b"]}

b = dict()

for key, value in a.items():
     b[str(key).replace('"','')] = value

ab = OrderedDict(sorted(b.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

for x in ab:
    ab[x].sort

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ab), content_type="application/json")
```

the output I am getting is

```
{ "A" : ["a", "c", "b"], "B" : ["x", "z", "k"]}
```

can anyone tell me where is my mistake? I am printing out in django template json output.

Comment: what method? I am printing out as json in django template output.

Comment: ... The `sort` method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the `sort` method. Just specifying `sort` will return a reference to the `sort` method, which isn't even assigned anywhere in your case. In order to actually call it, you should add parenthesis:

```
for x in ab:
    ab[x].sort()
    # Here ---^
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer and accepted it. I don't know who else did it.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you have a typo in your snippets, but here's one way to sort the values of a dictionary, where the values are lists:

```
>>> d1 = {"B" : ["x", "z", "k"], "A" : ["a", "c", "b"]}
>>> d2 = {x:sorted(d1[x]) for x in d1.keys()}
>>> d2
{'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['k', 'x', 'z']}
```

Comment: More specifically, this results in a *new* dictionary where the value lists are sorted. This may or may not be what is desired.

Comment: Well, that would need clarification from the asker, I guess. :|

Comment: @AlexReynolds, your answer kinda helped me. But the other answer was perfect. Thank you for helping me anyways. :D I really appreciate it.